# «Каррирование» str.format

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть шаблон строки, который я хочу заполнить значениями за два (или за N) вызова `str.format()`:

```
template = 'foo{a}bar{b}buzz'
```

Сначала так:

```
step1 = template.format(a=' A ')
print (step1)

> foo A bar{b}buzz
```

Потом:

```
step2 = step1.format(b=' B ')
print(step2)

> foo A bar B
```

Однако Python не позволяет передать в `format()` список меньшего размера или словарь не со всеми значениями.

Можно ли как-то выполнить «каррирование», то есть частичный `str.format()`? (Я понимаю, что это совсем не каррирование, поэтому кавычки. Grundy подсказывает, что это можно называть «частичным применением»).

---

Разумеется, я могу сделать так:

```
'foo{a}bar{b}buzz'.format(a=' A ', b='{b}')
```

Но это грязный хак, мне он не нравится тем, что нужно каждый раз перечислять параметры, то есть способ не универсален.

Ещё можно использовать чистое каррирование и создавать промежуточный объект-метод. Но он не является строкой, его нельзя передать в какой-то сторонний метод, который ждет именно строку.

---

Интересны решения для Python2 и Python 3.

Comment: ты можешь создать функцию принимающую первый аргумент, которая будет возвращать функцию принимающую второй аргумент, и в которой уже будет вызов format с двумя полученными значениями. В принципе твой случай [тут](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-python_details_03/index.html#N10253)

Comment: @Grundy да, я кажется даже читал этот документ. Но это довольно негибко. Как обычно, я надеюсь на магию вроде `import antigravity`.

Comment: И такое действительно есть :-)

Comment: @Grundy да-да, люблю эту историю с комиксом.

Comment: а как комментарии в питоне ставятся?

Comment: хотя что-то вот смотрю, похоже ответ не подходит под требования

Comment: @Grundy ну да, промежуточный результат нельзя передать как строку  методу, который ждет строку. Но все равно плюс.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62126/discussion-between-grundy-and-nick-volynkin).

Comment: То что `''.format` требует все переменные указать это достоинство. Старые среды заставляли явно включать это, например,  implicit none в фортране или use strict в перл, safe_substitute в string.Template в питоне. Если после передачи только части обязательных параметров в функцию вы не хотите получить функцию (с меньшим кол-вом параметров), то посмотрите не относится ли ваш вопрос к категории XY-задачи и нет ли лучшего подхода к оригинальной проблеме (даже если можно было бы переопределять текущее поведение str.format)

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае нужно не каррирование, а частичное применение.

Для этого используется [функция `partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) из модуля [functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#module-functools)

например:

```
from functools import partial
template = 'foo{a}bar{b}buzz';
fun = partial(template.format, a='w');

print( fun(b='dd') );
```

**[Repl.it](https://repl.it/J0Ds)**

Answer (score 6):

Если в форматируемой строке подставляемые значения обрамлены пробелами, как в вопросе, то удобно использовать `string.Template'.

```
from string import Template
temp = Template('foo $a bar $b buzz')

temp.safe_substitute(a='test')

>>> 'foo test bar $b buzz'

temp.substitute(a='test', b='val')

>>> 'foo test bar val buzz'
```

Если пробелов не должно быть, то уже не так красиво и надо учитывать, могут ли быть пробелы в подставляемой строке, или выбрать другой разделитель в `Template`:

```
strfmt = 'foo{}bar{}buzz'
temp = Template('$a $b')
strfmt.format(*temp.safe_substitute(a='TEST').split())
```