# Как подставить числа в строку?

Tags: python, for, format, строки

Как позиционно подставить числа в строку, чтобы получить ссылку с датой определенного формата. Как менять значение год, месяц день, в цикле `for`, чтобы сохранялась вложенность календаря, проходя от 1 до 30 дня, от 1 до 12 месяца, от 2005 до 2022 года.

Что было сделано?

Подставляю одно число.
Пример кода:

```
url = 'https://www.web.com/year=2022&month=02&day={}'

for i in range(1, 32):
    url_add = url.format(str(i))
    print(url_add)
```

Пробую подставить несколько чисел.

```
url = 'https://www.webua.com/year={1}&month={2}&day={3}'
for i1 in range(2005, 2022):
    url_add_1 = url.format(str(i1)) #  https://www.webua.com/year=2005&month={2}&day={1}

    for i2 in range(1, 13):
        url_add_2 = url_add_1.format(str(i2))   #  https://www.webua.com/year=2005&month=1&day={1}

        for i3 in range(1, 32):
            url_add_3 = url_add_2.format(str(i3))       #  https://www.webua.com/year=2005&month=1&day=1
            print(url_add_3)
```

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться, как правильно написать код используя только цикл `for` и метод `format`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [«Каррирование» str.format](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691722/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-str-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `f-строки`, они довольно быстро работают, не нужно экономить на том, чтобы по частям заниматься подстановкой:

```
url_base = 'https://www.webua.com/'
for year in range(2005, 2022):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        for day in range(1, 32):
            url = f'{url_base}year={year}&month={month}&day={day}'
            print(url)
```

Ну или если `f-строки` нельзя, то опять же подставляйте сразу все значения внутри циклов, вам же не нужны промежуточные значения, вы их только для некоей экономии ресурсов вычисляете?

```
url.format(year, month, day)
```

Comment: ещё можно записать так `f'{url_base}{year=}&{month=}&{day=}'`

Comment: @Danis это в совсем свежих версиях только, в Google Colab не работает )  Так то удобная штука, конечно.

Comment: это появилось в версии 3.8

Comment: @Danis А там до сих пор 3.7.12